# Removing float occurences from a list in the same cell python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of floats but the floats are in the same cell sometimes, seperate with a "," and I would like to remove the floats in the same cell with the same occurence.

I have tried a code on string (see below) and it works but it doesn't work with float.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
df['Desired'] = (df['NEIGHBORS'].str.split()
                          .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                          .str.join(','))
```

The message error is the following: 'float' object is not iterable.

[image: Here is a part of my list]

[Here is a part of my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlBsy.png)

Comment: Give an example input and the required output, this is not clear ? Do you want to concat a set (unique) of the floats of each line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, just make sure all your rows are string before iterating/applying over them:

```
# Add .astype(str) to avoid getting a TypeError
df['Desired'] = (df['NEIGHBORS'].astype(str).str.split()
                          .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                          .str.join(','))
```

That said, perhaps a better approach would be to only split the rows which are in fact strings:

```
df['Desired'] = (df['NEIGHBORS'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.split(','))) if isinstance(x, str) else x))
```

PS: I am using `set` for convenience, which will not preserve the order of your items. You can sort with an `OrderedDict` if order matters.

Comment: Thank you. However, my rows are only float and I would like to do it with float.

Comment: They cannot possibly be only floats with multiple commas per line. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry I did your second code and it works! Thanks a lot!